# Use While loop to calculate values from Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a following Table Where I need to loop through the records and add values to a variable

```
Declare @Variable1 INT
SET @Variable1=0

Declare @totalval INT
SET @totalval=0

While (@Variable1<=20)
BEGIN
SET @totalval=@totalval+(Select Salary from EmpTable Where EmpID=9)
PRINT @totalval
SET @Variable1= Variable1+1
END
GO
```

I cant print the value...I am using SQL server 2005

Thank you all

Comment: why are you looping at all, can't you use `SUM()`?

Comment: NO i cannot use SUM..its a requirement

Comment: There seems to be an error in `SET` statement .You are missing `@` for `variable1` inside the `while look`

Comment: @Kyle, can you explain why you have this requirement?

Comment: @praveen, you are correct, see my answer. I was getting an error as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also working (for your requirement):

[Fiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7fc5d/4)

```
declare @total int, @records int = 20 

select top( @records) @total=isnull(@total,0) + salary
from EmpTable
where empid = 9
-- order by salary (you may need to order by something)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use this instead:

```
;WITH a AS
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) num
            , *
    FROM    EmpTable
    WHERE   EmpID = 9

)

SELECT  @totalval = SUM(Salary)
        , @Variable1 = COUNT(*)
FROM    a 
WHERE   num <= 20
```

This would be one of usual ways of doing such task and it's more efficient than looping. `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0))` gives ordinal numbers to records but doesn't change sort.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
SET @Variable1= Variable1+1
```

that doesn't work, change it to this:

```
SET @Variable1= @Variable1+1
```

**if you were to leave it you should be getting this error:**

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Invalid column name 'Variable1'.
```

Comment: @Kyle, okay. So change it to the second line I gave you and the print will work. And next time, ***please*** include any errors you're getting. The question simply states `I cant print the value`. That leads people to believe that there is something wrong with the `PRINT` statement when there isn't.